# Variant Type in C#

Tags: c#, types

VBA (and I assume VB) has a Variant type which I believe takes up more memory, but covers various data types.

Is there an equivalent in c# ?

In a windows form say I had the following, how would I amend the type of z so that it runs ok

```
    private void uxConvertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 10;

        byte j = (byte)x;
        upDateRTB(j);

        long q = (long)x;
        upDateRTB(q);

        string m = x.ToString();
        upDateRTB(m);
    }

    void upDateRTB(long z) {
        MessageBox.Show(this,"amount; "+z);
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
void upDateRTB(object z) {
    MessageBox.Show(this, "amount; " + Convert.ToString(z));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

An object parameter would accept all, but if you'd like to keep the variables strongly typed (and avoid boxing in the process), you could use generics:

```
void upDateRTB<T>(T z) {
    MessageBox.Show(this,"amount; "+ Convert.ToString(z)); 
}
```

The method calls could remain precisely the same, because the compiler can resolve the generic type based on the given parameter.

Comment: I'm a c# newbie; this syntax for `generics`: `<T>(T z)` isn't something I've come across yet

Answer (score 7):

If you're talking about *"variant"* type in c#, take a look at `dynamic` type in .net 4.0

But for solving your task it would be enough to use `z.ToString()` in your `MessageBox.Show`

Answer (score 3):

The dynamic keyword or the object type could give you the variant behavior you want but:

In this case I'd change the function to:

```
void upDateRTB(string z) {
    MessageBox.Show(this,"amount; " + z);
}
```

Because that's all the method needs.

Comment: just changing the parameter to string doesn't work - try it. I'd need to amend other code aswell then. I'm just going to amend to object

Comment: Something you need to consider is the use of the function. Do you want it to accept ANY type?

Comment: exactly - I'd like to be able to add extra sections that call the function using other types than the 3 I've specified in the OP

Comment: If so, you Will have to make sure all the types that are being passed implement ToString in a way that makes sense being prefixed with amount. Having string as the type of the parameter forces and allows the caller to specify the text exactly.

Answer (score 3):

`"amount; "+z` implicitly calls the ToString method on `z`.
So you can use type `object`:

```
void upDateRTB(object z) {
    MessageBox.Show(this,"amount; "+z);
}
```

You can also use dynamic, but I don't see the point:

```
void upDateRTB(dynamic z) {
    MessageBox.Show(this,"amount; "+z);
}
```

Comment: has `dynamic` got more overhead? is that why you choose `object` instead?

Comment: yes, it has. dynamic needs to figure out the type at run time