# C# Equivalent for C++ std::variant (sum type / discriminated-union)

Tags: c#, variant

In C++ we have `std::variant` for creating a [sum-types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) (AKA  discriminated-union).
For example, the following will allow `v` to hold either a `std::string` or an `int`:

```cpp
#include <variant>
#include <string>

//...

std::variant< std::string, int> v;
v = "aaa";  // now v holds a std::string
v = 5;      // now v holds an int
```

In addition - the compiler will enforce that you assign `v` only with values convertible to `std::string` or `int`.

I am looking for a similar construct in C#.
Had a look at this post: [Variant Type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046622/variant-type-in-c-sharp),
but it didn't offer the proper equivalent I am looking for.

Is there one in C#?

---

Edit:
The SO post [Discriminated union in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151702/discriminated-union-in-c-sharp) is related but does not exactly answer my question because I am looking for a general language construct and not for a solution for a specific case.
However one of the answers mentioned the OneOf library, which is also one of the solutions in the accepted answer here.

Comment: That would be `object`. Eventually C# may be getting a [discriminated union](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/discriminated-unions.md).

Comment: But `object` can hold any type, isn't it ? If so it's not a good replacement for a real sum type like `std::variant`.

Comment: `object` is all you have for that at the moment (I don't think `dynamic` will do what you want)

Comment: Is there a particular use case you are trying to achieve? Probably "the C# way" (one way at least), is a custom class with implicit/explicit cast operators defined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discriminated union in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151702/discriminated-union-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @BurnsBA I don't have a specific problem. I was trying to answer another SO C# question and thought using a sum type would be proper. But I coudn't find a good way to have it in C#. Which made me curious how that can be achieved in general. The accepted answer here offer some good solutions IMHO.

Comment: The accepted answer builds implicit and explicit cast operator for you, which is probably about as good as it will get until native support is added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Either` monad from library [language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext#optional-and-alternative-value-monads). Install `LanguageExt.Core` NuGet package.

```
using LanguageExt;

//...

Either<string, int> v;
v = "aaa";
v = 5;
```

Or you could use [OneOf](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf) library. Install `OneOf` NuGet package.

```
using OneOf;

//...

OneOf<string, int> v;
v = "aaa";
v = 5;
```

*UPDATE*

Just to point it out: LanguageExt supports only 2 types in the `Either` struct. But `OneOf` supports up to 8 types. Although I am not aware which one is more performant and feature rich.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `object`

```
  object v;
  v = "aaa";
  v = 42;
```

Comment: Any idea how to enforce that the values are only `string`s or `int`s (like the compiler would enforce with `std::variant`) ?

Comment: @wohlstad maybe you can try to cast to your specific type before using them, something like `int.TryCast()` of course you would have to use a generic implementation

Comment: @DonMiguelSanchez the accepted answer above offers a solution for the time being. And hopefully C# will eventually get native discriminated union language support.