# in c# assume to be one class if it isn't another

Tags: c#

I have a class called result - which can contain a value or an error message.   So there is a base class `Result<T>` - and a class `ResultSuccess<T>` and `ResultFailure<T>`.   If I call a function that returns `Result<T>` I can check if it's a failure quite nicely...

```cs
var result = DoSomething()
if (result is ResultFailure<T> failure)
    throw new Exception("it failed with {failure.ErrorMessage}");
```

but now I'm left with a problem - I *know* the result is a ResultSuccess - but how do I get it it in a compiler helped way.   I can do all sorts of things like add a value that throws a runtime error if you call it on failure - do a cast but it's all nasty - for instance:

```cs
    if (result is ResultSuccess<T> succces)
        return success.Value;
    throw new Exception( "getting here should be impossible")
```

or

```cs
    return ((ResultSuccess<T>) result).Value;
```

in the perfect world - I could somehow tell .net that there are only two possible types, so

```cs
    if (result is ResultFailure<T> failure)
        throw new Exception( "It failed with {failure.ErrorMessaqge}");
    // the compiler magically just knows...
    return result.Value;
```

but if it's possible I don't know how to do it.   I can use switch pattern matching - but then I also need to account for the "other" case.   Is there any more elegant way to do it?
(what I currently do is the last one - define Value on the base class and just throw an error if you call it on an error... but it's.... impure).

Comment: Once you have a base class and derived types, *nothing* in the type system guarantees exactly how many derived types will exist either now or in future maintenance.

Comment: Well, one could argue: why are you using that result construct, if you are going to throw exceptions anyway? C# doesn't have discriminated unions (yet), so either use something that gets as close as it can or just use exceptions. I don't see how using _both_ would make sense (outside a 3rd party that uses a different paradigm than you chose to use).

Comment: Are you looking for [OneOf](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf)?

Comment: If you need a type that can be only one of 2 subtypes, you might use a **sum type / discriminated-union**. See the answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74520239/c-sharp-equivalent-for-c-stdvariant-sum-type-discriminated-union.

Comment: You shouldn't be throwing exceptions for situations as code flow. You should return your `Result<T>` object from your method and handle the result in the calling code.

Comment: I like oneOf - might steal some of the ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no sealed type hierarchies in C#. You are *going* to handle the "neither success nor failure" case at some point, by throwing an exception or whatever.

This case could be handled inside the `Result<T>` itself, so that you don't clutter the code that consumes `Result<T>`, which I assume is your ultimate goal.

You can redesign `Result<T>` to use nullable types to represent the two cases. This allows you to use nullability analysis attributes to ensure that `ErrorMessage` and `Value` do have a value in their respective branches of the `if`.

```
class Result<T> {
    public string? ErrorMessage { get; private init; }
    // note that this breaks down when T is a value type - you might want to have a separate ValueResult type constrained to value types
    public T? Value { get; private init; }
    
    private Result() {}
    
    public static Result<T> Success(T value) =>
        new() { Value = value };
     
    public static Result<T> Failure(string errorMessage) =>
        new() { ErrorMessage = errorMessage };
    
    [MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(Value))]
    [MemberNotNullWhen(false, nameof(ErrorMessage))]
    public bool IsSuccess {
        get {
            if (Value != null) return true;
            if (ErrorMessage != null) return false;
            throw new UnreachableException(); // or some other exception
        }
    }
}
```

The code consuming `Result` would be able to write

```
if (result.IsSuccess) {
    // result.Value is not null here
} else {
    // result.ErrorMessage is not null here
}
```

Comment: this is awesome - I didn't know about these MemberNotNull when true attributes - ty!

Answer (score 2):

It's not really possible in C#. For such cases, there is an builtin exception type, the `System.Diagnostics.UnreachableException` ([Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.unreachableexception?view=net-7.0)). So you could write it like this:

```cs
if (result is ResultSuccess<T> success) 
{
    // success
}
else if (result is ResultFailure<T> failure)
{
    // failure
}
throw new UnreachableException("result shouldn't be anything except ResultSuccess<T> or ResultFailure<T>.");
```

It's still not very nice but it's more developer-friendly than a property you sometimes can use and sometimes not.

Comment: Note that `UnreachableException` is not available in .NET 6.

Comment: It is in 7.0 tho.

Comment: Yes it is added in .net 7

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to extract the value, you could have a method on the base class for this:

```
public T GetValue() => this switch 
    {
        SuccessResult<T> success => success.Value,
        FailureResult<T> failure => throw new Exception(failure.ErrorMessage),
        _ => throw new NotSupportedException()
    };
```

But I think if you start using the monads, you should use them further. Do not extract the result value, just create the Map and Bind methods and use those.

Comment: `Map` and `Bind` are `Select` and `SelectMany` in .NET.